# How to create a tuple <input,output> where input is text in the column and output as row number?

Tags: python, excel, tuples, rbm

I have a csv file with Name Mobile Email headers. I want to generate a tuple which has input as a name,email or mobile and output as the corresponding row number. (input,output) tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

> The csv module’s reader and writer objects read and write sequences.
>   Programmers can also read and write data in dictionary form using the
>   DictReader and DictWriter classes.

You can use this CSV module to do the functionality.

```
import csv
with open('my_file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    file_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in file_reader:
        my_tuple= tuple(row)
        print(my_tuple)
```

For writing in the file you can use .writerow() function

```
fieldnames = ['Name', 'Mobile','Email']
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow({'Name': x, 'Mobile': y,'Email':z})
```

`x`,`y`,`z` are variables

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean by tuples?

```
import csv 
with open('file.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for tup in enumerate(reader):
        print(tup)
```

Output:

```
(0, OrderedDict([('name', 'abc'), ('email', 'def@geh.ijk'), ('phone', '12345678')]))
(1, OrderedDict([('name', 'lmn'), ('email', 'opq@rst.uvw'), ('phone', '23456789')]))
```